# How to access private property (with prefix # syntax) in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, access-modifiers, private-members

How do I acccess private property of a class denoted by prefix # symbol in TypeScript.
I need it for unit testing.

```js
class A {
    #pr: number;
    pu: number
    constructor(pr: number, pu: number) {
        this.#pr = pr;
        this.pu = pu;
    }
}

let a = new A(10, 9);

console.log(a.pu, a.#pr);
```

Tried this, `console.log(a.pu, a["#pr"]);` but no success.

Comment: TypeScript would use `private pr: number;`, `#` private properties are still only stage 3 with TC39 (see https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). In fact with TypeScript you can write that whole class `class A { constructor(private pr: number, public pu: number) { } }`. Also note you can't mix dot and bracket notation like that in JS or TS, it's `a.b` or `a['b']`.

Comment: if its just for unit-testing, why not cast `a` to `any` type?

Comment: Fields with `#` are truly private, you can't access them from outside

Comment: @jonrsharpe typescript adds polyfill for private properties, you can already use them https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#ecmascript-private-fields

Comment: @AlonYampolski type assertion won't help with private fields

Comment: @AlekseyL. oh interesting, thanks for pointing that out. I wondered if they might get used for the *output* on `private` fields at some point when targeting recent runtimes, sounds like that's not the direction they're going.

Comment: Also one thing that hasn't been mentioned here but probably should: test *behaviour*, through the public API; wanting to access private (`private` *or* `#`) fields and methods suggests a design problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to access or even detect the use of (non-polyfilled) private fields. That makes them *hard-private*.

You can read some of the reasoning in [this proposal discussion](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-fields/issues/33).